How to Calculate Roll and Pitch Relative to Frisbee Velocity Using IMU Data?
I have a imu attached to the center underside of a frisbee. It has an accelerometer and gyroscope built in. I would like to get the roll and pitch relative to the velocity of the frisbee. (Basically the roll and pitch at the moment of releasing the frisbee.) Since the frisbee and IMU are spinning how do I get the roll and pitch relative to the velovity direction of the frisbee?
Thank you for your help!
